# git for windows - does not load %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig when launched "run as"

Tags: windows, git

When I run command  `git config --list --show-origin` it shows entries from .gitconfig located in home directory. If I launch command prompt using **runas**, same command does not show entries from %USERPROFILE%.gitconfig. I verified that file exist.
My aim is to run git as different user. All commands works fine except user name/e-mail is not taken from .gitconfig but default values are used. When I run `git config --global -e` vi shows path to .gitconfig in my home directory. When I run same command from command prompt launched using **runas**, vi shows path `c:\windows\system32\.gitconfig`

How to force git to load .gitconfig from home folder when command prompt launched runas?

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution. On Windows, the user's home directory is defined by the environment variable `USERPROFILE`. Git doesn't actually use it and instead reads the value of the env variable `HOME`. If it is not set, it combines `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` to build `HOME` variable. When running `runas`, `HOMEPATH` is set to `Windows\system32`.

Git should use `USERPROFILE` if you set the `HOME` variable accordingly:

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Comment: Ha, you did it! Don't you filed a bug report for this? It tortured me for years. Especially with credential helpers. I even create my own [Git credential helper](https://github.com/it3xl/bash-git-credential-helper)

Answer (score 0):

One more bug here, and I would recommend to use

in **CMD**

```
CD /D %SYSTEMDRIVE%\
@REM  Or just use "CD .."

SET HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

I.e. when you start **CMD** by using "Run as a different user" you must move out of the home directory of your Windows logon user.

But in **bash** will be enough to use

```
HOME=$USERPROFILE
```

because **bash** has another default startup folder.

**Bug Description**

Suppose you are logged into Windows as an *ITretyakov* account.
Your user profile directory would be *C:/Users/ITretyakov*.
You have a service account named as *some_automoation*.
And you're opening **CMD** console by using "Run as a different user" for the *some_automoation* account.
But what's important, your startup directory will be *C:/Users/ITretyakov*.
And *some_automoation* account has no any access rights for this directory.

Run

```
git config --global --list
```

and you'll receive the following error

```
fatal: failed to stat 'C:/Users/ITretyakov': Permission denied
```

Git wants to read current working directory and fails on it.
Now set working directory to the system drive (C:) or to any another location.

```
CD /D %SYSTEMDRIVE%\
git config --global --list
```

and you'll receive another expecting error

```
fatal: unable to read config file 'C:/Windows/system32/.gitconfig': No such file or directory
```

and finally we use the fix of [zdenko.s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019492/git-for-windows-does-not-load-userprofile-gitconfig-when-launched-run-as/44041236#44041236)

```
SET HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Now you are ready to access .gitconfig of the **some_automoation** account that is located in
C:/Users/some_automoation

Conditions:
git version 2.21.0.windows.1;
Windows 10